# Is there a ruby/rails gem that makes querying time ranges more easy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a project, I'd like to make counts of how many registrations I had in a certain time window, like this week, or last month. I ended up writing class methods / scopes like this:

```
  def self.this_week
    where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week).count
  end

  def self.last_week
    where(created_at: 1.week.ago.beginning_of_week..1.week.ago.end_of_week).count
  end
```

Isn't there an easier way, or some sort of gem that takes care of this? I only need this on a few models, and ideally also a way to easily change the attribute to updated_at for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Rails 5.2. You don't need additional gem for this. From 5.2 Rails has build in methods `all_day`, `all_week` etc.

[DateAndTime::Calculations](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_day)

Comment: Nice, but it seems it doesn't support things like last month.